# Android special crop library

Tags: java, android, bitmap, photo, crop

I need to crop images for a "Photoprint" app of mine. To create appropriate image for printing paper, image will be scaled up, scaled down and cropped by dragging to specific field of image in a frame. Only short edge or long edge of the image could have empty space, two edges shouldn't have empty spaces at the same time. Any of height or width should fit the crop frame. By the way, crop frame should stay the same size. For example; for a 5x7" printing paper, frame will have 504x306px size.

Could you help me, image crop algorithm?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a question in here?

Comment: Basically, I need special crop library or crop algorithm.